# How can I make comments/descriptions in MQL4 code?

Tags: mql4, mql, description-logic

In python and other languages, you can write a multiline description like this:

```py
def func():
   '''
   this is my function description
   '''
   pass
```

How do you do this in MQL4?

Answer (score 1):

You use two forward slashes, for example

```
void function()
{
   // Description
}
```

If you want to use multi-line descriptions, you can block out portions of code, for example

```
void function()
{
   /*
   Description line 1
   Description line 2
   */
}
```